# Iterate elements inside foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to iterate through a nested array

```
        $row = 7;
        $i = 0;
        foreach($studentsInfo as $data) {
                $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValue('A' . $row, $data[$i]);
                $row++;
                $i++;
        }
```

but the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUzgv.png) came up.

I tried to use the "for" loop inside my "foreach" loop but the data is duplicated.

```
        $row = 7;
        foreach($studentsInfo as $data) {
            $studentLength = count($data);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $studentLength; $i++) {
                $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValue('D' . $row, $data[$i]);
                $row++;
            }
        }
```

Here's the [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srUTe.png) of the array

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this code:

```
$row = 7;
$i = 0;
foreach($studentsInfo as $data) {
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue('A' . $row, $data[$i]);
        $row++;
        $i++;
}
```

You take for granted that $data would would contain indexes like

```
[0] item1
[1] item2
[2] item3
[3] item4
```

etc.

When you do not actually know the key you should it like this when using `foreach`:

```
$row = 7;
foreach($studentsInfo as $data) {
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A' . $row, $data);
    $row++;
}
```

if it's just the value your interested in for each item in the array (`$data`)

If you have an array in array then just do a foreach-loop inside:

```
foreach($studentsInfo as $data) {
    foreach($data as $actual_value) {
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue('D' . $row, $actual_value);
        $row++;
    }
}
```

I hope you get "the picture" how you should move on.

Comment: It's a pretty clear explanation, thanks! If you look at the structure I presented, every nested array contains two elements. How can I output the elements with the first index then the second index etc.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried my last foreach? foreach($studentsInfo as $data) { ... then $data is the array.. you loop through that inner array by doing  foreach($data as $actual_value) { You don't have to care about the indexes/keys. Foreach takes care of that for you

Comment: I've tried but all the values displayed. I want my values with the first index to be displayed at first and only then the second ones etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean. Which values in which do you want to output? Please edit your question and type the array-structure and expected output in your question. (no images please)